# Bluetooth piconet

Tags: bluetooth

I have read about piconets and scatternets. However, everywhere I've checked I do not find anything that relates a "piconet" to a specific profile, say SPP.
My understanding is that the formation of a piconet is profile independent.

Secondly, if I have formed a piconet of upto 3 slaves, can I simply broadcast to all 3 slaves? Or do I have to unicast to multiple slaves i.e. implement TDM?

Thanks,
Angelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - Piconets and scatternets have nothing to do with Profiles.
They are just terminologies to define the topology of Bluetooth devices in connections.

Profiles define model and protocol for for the application level data transfers.

Yes you can broadcast to all slaves in a piconet provided the Bluetooth stack supports the functionality.

Comment: Any ideas if I can create a piconet using the HC-05 bluetooth module?